# Android запустить Yandex Навигатор

Tags: android, яндекс-навигатор

Возможно ли в Android программно запустить Yandex Навигатор и передать в него координаты точки А и точки Б, чтобы он начал прокладывать маршрут?

Мы заранее знаем что на устройстве 100% есть Яндекс Навигатор

Answer (score 7):

Можно. Взято [отсюда](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC):

```
// Создаем интент для построения маршрута
Intent intent = new Intent("ru.yandex.yandexnavi.action.BUILD_ROUTE_ON_MAP");
intent.setPackage("ru.yandex.yandexnavi");

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> infos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

// Проверяем, установлен ли Яндекс.Навигатор
if (infos == null || infos.size() == 0) {
    // Если нет - будем открывать страничку Навигатора в Google Play
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=ru.yandex.yandexnavi"));
} else {
    intent.putExtra("lat_from", 55.751802);
    intent.putExtra("lon_from", 37.586684);
    intent.putExtra("lat_to", 55.758192);
    intent.putExtra("lon_to", 37.642817);
}

// Запускаем нужную Activity
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно запустить вот так. Официальная документация

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("yandexnavi://build_route_on_map?lat_from=55.74&lon_from=37.60&lat_to=55.76&lon_to=37.64");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setPackage("ru.yandex.yandexnavi");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]